# Easiest way to Add lines wrong a .txt file to a list

Tags: c#, string, list, streamreader

At the moment I am opening the .txt file twice, once to get the number of all the lines, second to add a line to a list as much as how much lines there are in the .txt file. Is there an easier/better way to do this?

This is my code:

```
List<StreamReader> lijst = new List<StreamReader>();
StreamReader something1 = new StreamReader("C:\\something123.txt");
StreamReader something2 = new StreamReader("C:\\something123.txt");

lijst.Add(something1);
lijst.Add(something2);
{
    int l = 0;
    while (lijst[1].ReadLine() != null) 
    { 
        l++;
        downloadLinks.Add(lijst[1].ReadLine());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        String line = lijst[0].ReadLine();
        aList.Add(line);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you actually want to do something with the line? Or just count the number of them?

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` to read all lines in the file.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, "easiest way to add lines wrong"? Its not very often people ask how to do things the wrong way

Comment: I want to put all the lines of the file in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to put all the lines of the file in a list

Then you are working currently working too hard. You can use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx), which yields an `IEnumerable<string>` and pass that into a `List<string>`:

```
var allTextLines = new List<string>(File.ReadLines(path));
```

Comment: Why do you use a var for this?

Comment: `var` is just syntax sugar. Its actually a `List<string>`. For brevity mainly.

Comment: So I dont need to use StreamReader anymore? And I also dont have to use Dispose anymore so?

Comment: @wouter Nope. `File.ReadLines` will do that for you.

Comment: I cannot add the List allTextLines to another list tho? Is this because its a var? @Yuval Itzchakov

Comment: @wouter `aList.AddRange(allTextLines);`  as Braim mentioned in his answer

Comment: @wouter Yes, that's totally possible.

Comment: @wouter Maybe you also consider reading about the var keyword, as you seem to be confused a bit. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: I made a lot of these:  `var allTextLines = new List<string>(File.ReadLines(path));`and put them all in a list like this:`AlltextFiles.Add(allTextLines)` But how do I access the first line of the first list in this list? I tried this but didnt work: `String line = AlltextFiles[0].Readline();`

Comment: `allTextLines` is a List of strings (`List<string>`). What's `AlltextFiles`?

Comment: @Dolgsthrasir `AlltextFiles` is a list of lists I made it this way: `List<List<string>> AlltextFiles = new List<List<string>>();`

Comment: You could access the first line of first list with `AlltextFiles[0][0]` then. But remember to check for index boundaries.

Comment: @Dolgsthrasir I tried that but it didnt work. tells me:   `'string' does not contain a definition for 'ReadLine' and no extension method 'ReadLine' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to read all lines in one go. This way you don't need to iterate through a loop and the results are going to be in an Array that can be added in one call to any list you want.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
downloadLinks.AddRange(line);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx